# How to write an Eclipse QuickFix for Multiple Problems in Java-Source Files

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

During a refactoring of some legacy code the need came up to create our own Eclipse Quick Fix to do some small corrections to the code. This (in itself) was simple enough following this article (in German):
http://jaxenter.de/artikel/Eclipse-JDT-um-eigene-Quickfixes-erweitern

The quick fix (`IQuickFixProcessor`) is added through the extension point `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickFixProcessors` which creates a `IJavaCompletionProposal` to do the work. The `IQuickFixProcessor` has an AST readily available to do the code changes on.

The problem I am facing now, is that I can only apply the Quick Fix to one problem at a time. If I select multiple Problems (all of the same type, so my custom Quick Fix is applicable), I get the error "The selected problems do not have a common applicable quick fix".

How can I create a Quick Fix, that can be used for multiple problems of the same type?

Using the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution` as suggested by Acanda seems to be very difficult to implement for Java source files. For one there is no AST available, only an `IMarker` instance. How do I get the AST `CompilationUnit` and the offending `ASTNode` for an `IMarker`?

More general: Is there an API bridge in JDT to work with `IMarker` instances`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To support fixing multiple problems at the same time your quick fix has to implement `org.eclipse.ui.views.markers.WorkbenchMarkerResolution` and must be registered using the extention point `org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution`. The following example is from the Eclipse plug-in eclipse-pmd:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution">
   <markerResolutionGenerator
        class="ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.java.resolution.PMDMarkerResolutionGenerator"
        markerType="ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.core.pmdMarker">
   </markerResolutionGenerator>
</extension>
```

It is indeed a bit tricky to create a `CompilationUnit` from an `IMarker` and even trickier to find the offending `ASTNode`. Have a look at the abstract class [ASTQuickFix](https://github.com/acanda/eclipse-pmd/blob/master/ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.java/src/ch/acanda/eclipse/pmd/java/resolution/ASTQuickFix.java#L152) from eclipse-pmd. It creates a `CompilationUnit` from an `IMarker` and delegates finding the `ASTNode` to its subclasses which can define their own node finding strategy, e.g. [NodeWithinPositionNodeFinder](https://github.com/acanda/eclipse-pmd/blob/master/ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.java/src/ch/acanda/eclipse/pmd/java/resolution/NodeWithinPositionNodeFinder.java).

Comment: Should I extend the IQuickFixProcessor or the IJavaCompletionProposal?

Comment: The [QuickFixHandler tests if the quick fix implements WorkbenchMarkerResolution](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3/org.eclipse.ui/ide/3.9.0/org/eclipse/ui/internal/views/markers/QuickFixHandler.java#94).

Comment: I see. I have a feeling, that I might be using a wrong/old extension point: "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickFixProcessors". Is there another extension point to add marker resolutions?

Comment: I think I found the correct extension point: "org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution". Using this I would have to figure out, how to get the AST with an IMarker instance ...

Answer (score 1):

To get a `ASTNode` for a `IMarker`:

```
public ASTNode getASTNodeFromMarker(IMarker marker) {
    IResource res = marker.getResource();
    if (res.getType() == IResource.FILE) {
        IFile f = (IFile)res;
        ICompilationUnit cu = (ICompilationUnit)JavaCore.create(f);
        CompilationUnit astRoot = getAstRoot(cu);
        int start = marker.getAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, 0);
        int end = marker.getAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, 0);
        NodeFinder nf = new NodeFinder(astRoot, start, end-start);
        return nf.getCoveringNode();
    }
    return null;
}

private CompilationUnit getAstRoot(ITypeRoot typeRoot) {
    CompilationUnit root = SharedASTProvider.getAST(typeRoot, SharedASTProvider.WAIT_YES, null);
    if (root == null) {
        ASTParser astParser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
        astParser.setSource(typeRoot);
        astParser.setResolveBindings(true);
        astParser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
        astParser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
        root = (CompilationUnit)astParser.createAST(null);
    }
    return root;  // may return null if no source available for typeRoot
}
```